# Custom Document Set content type created through code has null Welcome Page Fields in template

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, content-type, 2016, document-set

I am creating a custom Document Set content type through server-side/C# code as follows:

```
SPContentType docSet = web.AvailableContentTypes["Document Set"];
SPContentType newCType = new SPContentType(docSet, web.ContentTypes, "My Custom Doc Set");
newCType = web.ContentTypes.Add(newCType);
newCType.Group = "My Content Types";
newCType.Update();
```

I then proceed to add some fields by creating new `FieldLink` objects and adding them to the `newCType.FieldLinks` collection.

I then proceed to update the `WelcomePageFields` XML document in the `newCType.XmlDocuments` as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, string> welcomPageFieldsList = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    "Field1InternalName", "field-1-guid",
    "Field2InternalName", "field-2-guid"
    // etc
}

XNamespace xlmns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepagefields";
XElement welcomPageFieldsXML = new XElement(xlmns + "WelcomePageFields");

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> fieldInfo in welcomPageFieldsList)
{
    XElement fieldElement = new XElement("WelcomePageField",
        new XAttribute("Name", fieldInfo.Key),
        new XAttribute("id", fieldInfo.Value)
    );
    welcomPageFieldsXML.Add(fieldElement);
}

List<XElement> xmlDocs = newCType.XmlDocuments.Cast<string>().Select(doc => XElement.Parse(doc)).ToList();
XElement oldXmlDoc = xmlDocs.Find(oldDoc => oldDoc.Name.LocalName == welcomPageFieldsXML.Name.LocalName);
newCType.XmlDocuments.Delete(oldXmlDoc.Name.NamespaceName);
XmlDocument newXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
newXMLDoc.Load(welcomPageFieldsXML.CreateReader());
newCType.XmlDocuments.Add(newXMLDoc);
newCType.Update();
```

This all works fine, but when I try to create a new document set instance based on that content type in a document library, I get a `NullReferenceException` from the Welcome Page Fields webpart on the document set homepage.  I thought maybe I forgot to actually add one of the fields to the content type that I reference in the XML Documents, but no, they all match up.  So I dug into the ULS logs, and I see that actually the error is thrown because some part of the process is accessing the welcome page fields from the document set *template*, and that's what's throwing the exception.

So I tried adding code to get the template, and add the fields to the `WelcomPageFields` on the template, but that also threw a `NullReferenceException`.

So I did a little digging with Powershell, got my custom content type, and then got the `DocumentSetTemplate` object associated with my custom document set, and I see that the `WelcomePageFields` property is apparently `null`:

[image: Powershell screenshot]

According to the [documentation about the `DocumentSetTemplate.WelcomePageFields` property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.documentsettemplate.welcomepagefields?view=sharepoint-server), it's a read-only property, so I can't `new` up a `WelcomePageFieldCollection` and assign it to the template so everything gets hooked up properly.

So - **how do you properly create a custom content type based on Document Set using server-side/C# code so that the `WelcomePageFields` property of the *template* is initialized properly?**

---

Update:

It seems like the `WelcomePageFields` property on the template *is* an empty collection (not `null`) when the content type is initially created, and it's the process of deleting the old `WelcomePageFields` XML document from the content type that clears out the property on the template - even though I *replace* the XML document with another `WelcomePageFields` XML document before I call `Update()` on the content type?

Will be doing more research/experimentation, but could still use any pointers or suggestions for how to get this done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that it was indeed caused by deleting the `WelcomePageFields` XML document from the content type's `XmlDocuments` property.  Somehow that triggers the deleting of the `WelcomePageFieldCollection` on the *template*, making the template's `WelcomePageFields` property `null`, even though I had re-added a `WelcomePageFields` XML document to the `XmlDocuments` *before* I called `Update()` on the content type.

But, as it turns out, if you edit/update the `WelcomePageFields` on the *template*, it will automatically update the `XmlDocuments` on the *content type*.  So in the end all I needed to do was to add the fields I wanted to be on the Document Set homepage to the template and not touch the `XmlDocuments` at all.